# Fade in text on load

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, fadein, fade

I've seen that there are different ways to fade in an object on load but every time I try to apply it to my own code I must be messing something up. I've been trying css and javascript so I'm good to use whatever I can get working.

I would like Hello to fade up on load but then 5 seconds later Next Page also fade's in.

Here's my code so far.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<link href="sky.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="sky.js"></script>

</head>


<body>
    <div id="Welcome">
        <h1> Hello </h1>
        </div>

     <div id="Next"> 
        <a href="next.html"><h2> Next Page </h2></a>
    </div> 

    <video autoplay muted loop id="VidBackground">
        <source src="video/home.mp4">
    </video>


</body>
</html>
```

and here's my css

```
h1, h3, a {
    color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 2;
}

#welcome {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15%;
    right: 20%;
    z-index: 2;
}

#next {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
    right: 20%;
    z-index: 2;
}

#VidBackground {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be a good fit for CSS transitions.

You can use them like this:

`transition: <css property> <transition-duration> <transition-function>`

Example:

```
#next {
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;

    /*pointer-events makes this node not respond to mouse/touch events
    Which is probably what we want while the button is invisible.*/
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Now whenever the `opacity` style changes on `#next` it will transition instead of appearing instantaneous. Typically you would trigger it by some javascript.

```
window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        //Re-enable mouse/touch events on the #next button
        document.getElementById("next").style.pointerEvents = 'auto';

        //Show the #next button
        //Since opacity style is transitioned, the opacity change will automatically trigger the transition.
        document.getElementById("next").style.opacity = 1;
    }, 5000);
});
```

Further reading on transitions can be found over at the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition